# accessing elastic IP URL from internet

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have my EC2 in public subnet. Have configured an elastic IP to it. But the Applications inside it are not accessible from Internet i.e elastic IP URL is down. Why is this so?

Port -80 & 443 open,,,,,Firewall Open

What extra needs to be done?

Comment: Is the instance publicly accessible, are you able to connect on any other ports?

Comment: Instance is Accessible within My AWS VPC but not from internet. Requirement is to access an app running at 8080 from Internet.

Comment: Does the instance live in a subnet that has a internet gateway for internet traffic. Has your security group allowed inbound access on port 8080?

Comment: Yes Chris. Instance lives in a subnet that has an internet gateway attached.  Sec Group has 80 , 8080 and 443 open.....OS firewall open too

Comment: But my route table has a default route(0.0.0.0) pointed to a nat gateway not the aforesaid internet gateway. Is that the roadblock?

Comment: Yes @Ranjith the IGW is required (and would need to replace the NAT), any instances in that subnet would need to be publicly accessible otherwise they could not communicate with the internet. Have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subnet is having a route that speaks to a NAT Gateway.

To allow inbound traffic it must be an internet gateway. This allows bi-directional transit to the internet, whereas a NAT Gateway only allow outbound communication to the internet.

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Your application has to be listening on the correct address, usually there is a setting for the listen address.  Set it to 0.0.0.0/0 if you are unsure

The routing from the VPC has to be correct, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario1.html

As well as security groups there are Network ACLs, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html
the default is that these allow traffic but if someone else set up your VPC...